# Unclosed img tag breaks site but is not shown

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I want to create a simple site that can be broken with a Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability. The problem lies in the third and "hard" challenge which filters input with regex and removes everything that starts and ends with angle brackets. So, for example, `<img>` would be removed, but `<img` would not. That is also the key to solving the challenge - an unclosed void tag with malicious event attributes. The problem is that the `<img` tag (or any other unclosed tag) breaks the site but is not added to the DOM.

Everything is done by JavaScript. Clicking a button takes the value of the text box and assigns it to a paragraph's `innerHTML`. I have already tried other methods like `outerHTML`, or `insertAdjacentHTML()` but it all has the same result.

This is the HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
    <script src="script/xss_hard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="Logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" style="margin-top: 0px; width:150px;display:block" />
            <h2><span id="title">Search</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="logic">
        <input type="text" onclick="javascript:clearBox()" value="Search" id="box">
        <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="javascript:submit()" id="butt">
    </div>

    <p id="searchReflect"></p>
</body>
```

And this is the corresponding JavaScript:

```
function submit(){
    var reflect = document.getElementById('searchReflect');
    var boxText = document.getElementById('box').value;

    var blacklist = /<.*>/;

    boxText = boxText.replace(blacklist, '');

    reflect.HTML = "Your search for \"" + boxText + "\" returned nothing!";  
}
```

The expectation is, is that it is possible to inject e.g. `<img src="" onerror="alert(1)"` and get an alert popup (XSS). What actually happens is this (taken from Firefox inspector with "Edit as HTML"):

`<p id="searchReflect">Your search for "</p>`

The strange thing is, is that it breaks the output, but is still not run. Same thing with `svg`, `iframe`, or other tags. It SHOULD be, when filtered or properly embedded (`innerText`, for example):

`<p id="searchReflect">Your search for "foo" returned nothing!</p>`

Comment: I strongly recommend you work with DOM without `innerHTML`, if you want i can show you example

Comment: find my answer and run the code it will works. :)

Comment: @VadimHulevich I do not know what you mean. I would be happy to see an example - would that still run the code then? As I said, I need Cross-Site Scripting to work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to improve your code.

```
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script/xss_hard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="Logo">
           <img src="images/logo.png" style="margin-top: 0px;width:150px;display:block" />
            <h2><span id="title">Search</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logic">
        <input type="text" value="" id="box" placeholder="Search" />
        <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="submit()" id="butt" />
    </div>
    <p id="searchReflect"></p>  
</body>
```

And corresponding Javascript. I added jQuery in `<Head>` tag to make code simpler :) Javascript is too long to write so use jQuery instead of Javascript.

```
function submit(){
    var reflect = $('#searchReflect');
    var boxText = document.getElementById('box').value;
    var blacklist = /<.*>/;

    boxText = boxText.replace(blacklist, '');

    reflect.html('Your search for \'' + boxText + '\' returned nothing!');  
    $('#box').val('');
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that was not the question. The question is why it behaves the way it does and how I can fix it. jQuery doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: the Posted answer is run by me and it's works. No error of any image tag is showing.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me expected. The same thing is happening as before. I NEED the page to run the injected script.